# Moving item after constraint has been applied

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a table cell, and it has a label (which has the username), and a button (which takes to a location).  There are constraints set to be the same on the y axis (center vertically to each other) and 5 px trailing/leading to each other.  Works great.  What doesnt work great, is if the label text is extremely long.  It will push the text off the screen.  How do I make the button go down to below the label?  Similar to float in css?

[image]

^^This is the cell, and as you can see it goes off the screen.    I need "San Francisco, CA" to be pushed below the label "@VeryReallyReallyLongUsername".  I know you can do dynamic cell resizing using AutomaticDimension...

Comment: label is on left, button is on right?

Comment: what is set text in button or label ask?

Comment: As your text is long i.e mulitlines than you have to do numberoflines = 0 and change LineBreakMode from Truncate Tail to Word Warp

Comment: this works but it does push the button below the label.  Two differnet elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you should manage many thing programmatically. You can take outlet of constraint by `ctrl + dragging` from `constraint` to `class` file.

Then you can manipulate it's constant.

So if you want to let your button goes down when text is large then you can take outlet of top constraint of button and then increase it's `constant` by some pixels that you want and do same for label take outlet of it's width constraint and increase it's `constant` by some pixels that you want to increase width.

Second thing if you don't want to manage stuff like mentioned above then you can use multi line label. just set the `numberOfLines` property of your label to `0`.
So if text size will be large then label distributes in two line or three line.

Or you can set `Autoshrink` property from `attribute inspector` from IB(story board) to `minimum font size` and set minimum font size with it. so if text is larger then it reduce font size that it fits exactly to label but not reduce more than that minimum size that we have set.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Not easily. It may be possible to set up constraints which would do this, but I wouldn't know where to start.

I would pick another option such as having the label truncate the long value (it will put ... at the end), or to have the label scale the text smaller, or to have the label grow vertically and wrap the text.